# How many search results should there be on screen and how should I arrange them?

Tags: website-design, search, search-results

I am currently implementing a catalog for a light and sound rental service.

All items are shown as a picture on the left with a descriptive text on the right. The last 2 lines in the description are 1 line technical informations like "Power: 800W, 1 way 18" subwoofer. XLR in/out and out with lowpass". And the last line consists of buttons "More Informations", "Add to cart", "Compare".

In this catalog, how many items should be on screen at time, and how big should they be arranged. Should it be more like menu on the left and many small items on the right of the menu, or should the menu be on the top, and should there be many bigger items under that menu?

Answer (score 1):

It's common for search results pages to have an option to select the number of items displayed - this is so users can choose how many results they would like to see. Remember that different users will have different browsing styles - some may prefer 100 items on a page so they can scan quickly and use Cntrl-F to find a particular item on the page. Others may prefer a shorter page.

It may also be useful to have a faceted search - so that the user can narrow the search results by type or category. This might mean allowing users to choose to see search results in the 'audio' category, or the 'Sony brand' category.

It's also useful to allow the user to reorganise the search results. Many electronics websites allow users to see the results organised by price LOW > HIGH or HIGH > LOW.

Comment: OK that is very clear, but my original question wasn't really how many results there should be on a page (which is scrollable), but instead how many should be on a single screen (if you don't scroll over the page).

Comment: I think that really depends - is the page responsive? The image size and layout will change for different viewports.

Answer (score 1):

Laying out your screen elements has alot to do with how you think the user will interact with the search results.

> - how many items should be on screen at time?

As much as your the vertical constraints of your screen allows without compromising the adequate spacing between each item. Define a standard of spacing between each item balanced with the spacing between other elements of your screen

> - how big should they be arranged?

As big as necessary to fit the content of the item (image, description and buttons) making is easy to view, read, and interact with the buttons.

> Should it be more like menu on the left and many small items on the
>   right of the menu, or should the menu be on the top, and should there
>   be many bigger items under that menu?

Umm, what menu?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if on the search stage, you need to show a lot of important information, it may be only one result per row (ebay.com). If not, it may be 3 - 4 tiles per row with responsive width. (frequently used). Height of the row depends on proportion of image or size of additional information. I think, peoples more like squares then rectangles =), however i suggest to make tiles more squarry =)